# Microsoft Power BI Add Double Column

Tags: powerbi

I have table from Database with format below:

| id | object_name | stock | lowest_price | highest_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | milk | 100 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | bread | 95 | 5 | 15 |

I want to visualize in Power BI like this:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni5Np.png)

Is it possible? How I can do it?

I want to visualize it like the picture above

Comment: You sample input data is almost same you need as an output. Except the label "Price" on top of low and high price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you are trying to find a way to group the columns "lowest_price" and "highest_price" under the column header "Price", and then removing the word 'Price' from the other columns.

I've tried to do something similar when I had 8 columns that all had "Cumulative" in the name, thus removing the redundancy of having the word written out 8 times.

Unfortunately, **vanilla Power BI does not offer a way to group columns**. Here are two work arounds to this:

### Method 1: Detached Header, Fixed Column Width

You can add a textbox above the columns, and then turn off auto-size column width. This ensures that the columns in the table/matrix and the textbox is always aligned since they are separate objects.

To turn off auto-size: **Format > Column headers > Auto-size column width**

[This is what the end result will look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o5ZZ.png)

Cons: Static column width. If your table requires a horizontal scroll, this method will not work.

### Method 2: Custom Visual

Outside of vanilla Power BI, you can download custom visuals from Appsource to help you develop. For example, at this [link](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/xviz.inforiver-premium?exp=kyyw&tab=Overview), you can download a custom matrix that does allow you to group columns.

[You could end up with something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9i0a.png)

Unfortunately, most of these table/matrix custom visuals require a subscription.

Cons: Payed subscription. Learning how to use a new visual.

### Remarks

If your table/matrix is simple, I would highly recommend going with method 1 as it is very easy to implement and is free!

Comment: Thank you. I'm still beginner in Power BI